# Pass text data from select box

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

can anyone help me how to pass the selected `text` from all of my select(box) to their specific (`textboxes`).
Because the values of all the selectbox are all `id` integers and I'm planning to save the  text of each selectbox that I select to the database.

My script to pass selected text from selectbox to textbox is not working can anyone help me make it work?

html:

```
<form method="post">
Caraga Region: <select name="region" id="region"></select>
Municipalities: <select name="town" id="town"></select>
Unique ID: <select name="uniq_id" id="uniq_id"></select>
Position: <select name="position" id="position"></select> <br />
Salary Grade: <select name="salary_grade" id="salary_grade"></select>
Salary: <select name="salary" id="salary"></select> <br />
<br />
<br />
Transfer Selected Text to textbox:<br />
<input id="region" name="reg" type="text"><br />
<input id="town" name="t" type="text" ><br />
<input id="uniq_id" name="u" type="text" ><br />
<input id="position" name="p" type="text" ><br />
<input id="salary_grade" name="sg" type="text" ><br />
<input id="salary" name="s" type="text" ><br />
</form>
```

script code to fill data in the selectbox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() { 
   $("#region").jCombo({ url: "getRegion.php" } );
   $("#town").jCombo({ url: "getTown.php?townid=", parent: "#region", selected_value : '510' } );
   $("#uniq_id").jCombo({ url: "getID.php?unqid=", parent: "#town", selected_value : '150' } );
   $("#position").jCombo({ url: "getPosition.php?posid=", parent: "#uniq_id", selected_value : '150' } );
   $("#salary_grade").jCombo({ url: "getSalary_Grade.php?sgid=", parent: "#position", selected_value : '150' } );
   $("#salary").jCombo({ url: "getSalary.php?salaryid=", parent: "#salary_grade", selected_value : '150' } );
});
</script>
```

script to pass data from selected text from each `selectbox` to specific `textbox`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() { 
$("#region").document.getElementByID("region").options[document.getElementByID("region").selectedIndex].text
$("#town").document.getElementByID("town").options[document.getElementByID("town").selectedIndex].text
$("#uniq_id").document.getElementByID("uniq_id").options[document.getElementByID("uniq_id").selectedIndex].text
$("#position").document.getElementByID("position").options[document.getElementByID("position").selectedIndex].text
$("#salary_grade").document.getElementByID("salary_grade").options[document.getElementByID("salary_grade").selectedIndex].text
$("#salary").document.getElementByID("salary").options[document.getElementByID("salary").selectedIndex].text
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how JQuery selectors work. Also, you have duplicate IDs in your HTML. This is not valid HTML and will cause issues for you.

The following will work for you:

```
<form method="post">
Caraga Region: <select name="region" id="region"></select>
Municipalities: <select name="town" id="town"></select>
Unique ID: <select name="uniq_id" id="uniq_id"></select>
Position: <select name="position" id="position"></select> <br />
Salary Grade: <select name="salary_grade" id="salary_grade"></select>
Salary: <select name="salary" id="salary"></select> <br />
<br />
<br />
Transfer Selected Text to textbox:<br />
<input id="region2" name="reg" type="text"><br />
<input id="town2" name="t" type="text" ><br />
<input id="uniq_id2" name="u" type="text" ><br />
<input id="position2" name="p" type="text" ><br />
<input id="salary_grade2" name="sg" type="text" ><br />
<input id="salary2" name="s" type="text" ><br />
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() { 
$("#region2").attr('value', $('#region').text());
//etc...
});
</script>
```

Comment: No problem. Just make sure your IDs are always unique :)

Answer (score 0):

You should really make sure your IDs are unique.  I've added a prefix to them so they are valid.

```
<form method="post">
Caraga Region: <select name="region" id="s_region"></select>
Municipalities: <select name="town" id="s_town"></select>
Unique ID: <select name="uniq_id" id="s_uniq_id"></select>
Position: <select name="position" id="s_position"></select> <br />
Salary Grade: <select name="salary_grade" id="s_salary_grade"></select>
Salary: <select name="salary" id="s_salary"></select> <br />
<br />
<br />
Transfer Selected Text to textbox:<br />
<input id="t_region" name="reg" type="text"><br />
<input id="t_town" name="t" type="text" ><br />
<input id="t_uniq_id" name="u" type="text" ><br />
<input id="t_position" name="p" type="text" ><br />
<input id="t_salary_grade" name="sg" type="text" ><br />
<input id="t_salary" name="s" type="text" ><br />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() { 
    $("#t_region").val($( "#s_region option:selected" ).text());
    $("#t_town").val($( "#s_town option:selected" ).text());
    $("#t_uniq_id").val($( "#s_uniq_id option:selected" ).text());
    $("#t_position").val($( "#s_position option:selected" ).text());
    $("#t_salary_grade").val($( "#s_salary_grade option:selected" ).text());
    $("#t_salary").val($( "#s_salary option:selected" ).text());
});
</script>
```